# C# Sending Data over serial port between 2 PC using own Protocol

Tags: c#

I have an assignment where I need to load some data like `user (pouzivatel)` and some `int(stav odberu)` through link modem with the serial port and store it in my local database. I know how to load data, send data over the serial port, but I need to make it happen in a structure on the image.

[image: evisualisation]

First I dial the telephone number of the device with AT command, btw this is working, but I do not know now how to stop and wait for `SOH+adresa objektu` (SOH+some string about address). Then send data about confirmation (ACK) and wait for new data to come.

The wait sequence is my biggest problem. How do I stop and wait for data being received.

Comment: Well, make a blocking read call or use a wrapper component that fires an event on data rx.  There is a serial component in C# Toolbox by default.  It certainly has a 'DataReceived' event and probably has blocking methods that you could call in a thread, should you wish to.

Comment: Or just don't wait and use the DataReceived event.

Comment: C# has a serial component that i use. I can read incomming data on port and show them in a text box, that is easy, but i dont know how to program that picture above. i use the the data received handler
private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Using the component and utilizing its DataReceived event as suggested in the comments would probably solve your problem easy and effectively. But you may have been looking for something more low-level to do it yourself.

If you want/need to do it in-line without any fancy event based system that would assume you are already in some message queue based environment like WinForms, you could do something like this.

```
while (true)
{
  // check for new data
  ...
  // if you got some, respond to it
  ...

  if (someConditionThatTellsYouYouAreDoneOrSupposedToTerminate) break;

  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```